# Grab random entry in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, nsset

Is there a way to grab a totally random key in the NSDictionary?

```
NSString *key = [enumeratorForKeysInDictionary nextObject];
```

I have this code which iterates over the dictionary in a non-random way.

Should I add all the keys to an NSSet and then pull randomly from there?

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Since the order of enumeration will be "undefined" you could call that "random", but better would be to retrieve `allValues` and then randomly select entries from the resulting array.  (Or use `allKeys` and then fetch the associated value, if you need both key and value.)

Comment: @stackOverFlew Are you not satisied with my answer or you want something different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this:

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary allKeys];
int random = arc4random()%[array count];
NSString *key = [array objectAtIndex:random];
```

Comment: You don't need to call `srandom` with `arc4random`, but you should consider using `arc4random_uniform([array count])` to avoid modulo bias

Comment: i am unable to get this point that what is srandom and what will be its effect on above code

Comment: `[dictionary.allKeys objectAtIndex:arc4random()%dictionary.allKeys.count];`

Comment: @SimonWhitaker My comment about calling `srandom` applied when the original answer used `random` instead of `arc4random`.

Comment: thanks @Best Coder!! thanks @SimonWhitaker! original answer edited.

Comment: `arc4random()` will not be random if the number of objects in the array is not a power of 2.  `arc4random_uniform()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray* allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
id randomKey = allKeys[arc4random_uniform([allKeys count])];
id randomObject = dictionary[randomKey];
```

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(arg)` returns a random number less than arg. You don't need the modulo.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this:

```
NSArray* allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
```

Then you can c method rand() to get a random index in the above NSArray to get the random key.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea here, using a random index into keys, but a few improvements: (1) a dictionary category, (2) a block enumerator, like the native, (3) most important - to enumerate randomly, we must eliminate keys already visited.  This will visit each key randomly, exactly once (unless the caller sets stop=YES in the block):

```
//
//  NSDictionary+RandBlockEnum.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (RandBlockEnum)

- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsRandomlyUsingBlock:(void (^)(id, id, BOOL *))block;

@end


//
//  NSDictionary+RandBlockEnum.m
//

#import "NSDictionary+RandBlockEnum.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (RandBlockEnum)


- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsRandomlyUsingBlock:(void (^)(id, id, BOOL *))block {

    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self allKeys]];
    BOOL stop = NO;;

    while (keys.count && !stop) {
        id randomKey = keys[arc4random_uniform(keys.count)];
        block(randomKey, self[randomKey], &stop);
        [keys removeObject:randomKey];
    }
}

@end
```

Call it like this:

```
#import "NSDictionary+RandBlockEnum.h"

NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"k1" : @"o1", @"k2" : @"o2", @"k3" : @"o3" };
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsRandomlyUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", key, object);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern, one-line version of @BestCoder's answer:

#### Objective-C

```objective-c
dictionary.allKeys[arc4random_uniform(dictionary.allKeys.count)]
```

#### Swift

```swift
Array(dictionary.keys)[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dictionary.keys.count)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set and then grab any object from the set.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:[myDictionary allKeys]];
NSString *randomKey = [set anyObject];
```

Comment: From NSSet documentation: "The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience—the selection is not guaranteed to be random."

Comment: Good call! Thought it was supposed to be random.

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 4

you have a dictionary

```
        let ads = _segueDataFromHomeToGuessMatch_NSType[Constants.Matches.ads] as! NSDictionary
```

get a random key value like this

```
        let rd_ad_key = ads.allKeys[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ads.count)))] as! String
```

get value of the random key like this

```
    let rd_ad_value = ads[rd_ad_key] as! String
```