# Randomising Values in Dictionaries and displaying them in labels SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, random

so i'm trying so that when I click a button, it displays a random key from my dictionary which i have and then i click another button and it displays the data associated with that key for a small memory science app I am making. For example, I click the button and in the label says Hydrogen, then I click another button and it gives my the data saying the formula "H". So how do I make the label give me a random key from the dictionary when I click the button?

Thanks,
Riley

I'm in Xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grab random entry in NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841219/grab-random-entry-in-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can try in swift 4.2:

```
let randomkey = dict.keys.randomElement()
```

Or

```
let randomkey = dict.values.randomElement()
```

In when swift version < 4.2 then try this:

```
let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dict.count)))
let randomkey = Array(dict.keys)[index]
```

Comment: *"I'm in Xcode 9.4.1"* – `randomElement()` is a Swift 4.2 feature, you would need Xcode 10 (beta).

Comment: @MartinR: Yes , this is in swift 4.2